# How to use a theanets neural network model in deeplearning4j?

Tags: neural-network, deeplearning4j

I have trained theanets neural network model and I want to use the same model in deeplearning4j, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have keras model import if you can map it to that. That's as close as it's going to get though.

https://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras

Beyond that it depends on the mdoel.